# Anotate route and extend existing method inside

Tags: php, symfony, routes, shopware

I'm trying to **access** in symfony5 a **method called Register**. The **goal is to extend it**. So i'm trying to anotate a Route (as i read in the symfony documentation, ***anotation is hooking inside a existing route, right?***). But when executing it, nothing happens. The developer told me that the route is correct... I want to **send the register method after registration submission** and just get a simpel debug info message. (hello world). I'm using the Symfony profiler to show me alle messages timeline etc. but it does not showing up everywhere.

Here the Controller located in **/RegisterFormExtension/src/Storefront/Controller/CustomRegisterController.php** with the already existing method **register** obtained from **RegisterRoute**

```
<?php
namespace RegisterFormExtension\Storefront\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\RegisterRoute;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\CustomerResponse;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataValidationDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\RequestDataBag;

class CustomRegisterController extends RegisterRoute{
    /**
     * @Route("/store-api/v{version}/account/register", name="store-api.account.register", methods={"POST"})
     */
    //@Route("/account/register",  name="frontend.account.register.save")

    public function register(RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context, bool $validateStorefrontUrl = true, ?DataValidationDefinition $additionalValidationDefinitions = null): CustomerResponse
    {
        $isGuest = $data->getBoolean('guest');
        $this->validateRegistrationData($data, $isGuest, $context, $additionalValidationDefinitions, $validateStorefrontUrl);

        $customer = $this->mapCustomerData($data, $isGuest, $context);

        /** @var DataBag $billing */
        $billing = $data->get('billingAddress');

        if ($data->has('title')) {
            $billing->set('title', $data->get('title'));
        }

        $billingAddress = $this->mapBillingAddress($billing, $context->getContext());
        $billingAddress['id'] = Uuid::randomHex();
        $billingAddress['customerId'] = $customer['id'];

        // if no shipping address is provided, use the billing address
        $customer['defaultShippingAddressId'] = $billingAddress['id'];
        $customer['defaultBillingAddressId'] = $billingAddress['id'];
        $customer['addresses'][] = $billingAddress;

        if ($shipping = $data->get('shippingAddress')) {
            $shippingAddress = $this->mapShippingAddress($shipping, $context->getContext());
            $shippingAddress['id'] = Uuid::randomHex();
            $shippingAddress['customerId'] = $customer['id'];

            $customer['defaultShippingAddressId'] = $shippingAddress['id'];
            $customer['addresses'][] = $shippingAddress;
        }

        if ($data->get('accountType') === CustomerEntity::ACCOUNT_TYPE_BUSINESS && !empty($billingAddress['company'])) {
            $customer['company'] = $billingAddress['company'];
        }

        $customer = $this->setDoubleOptInData($customer, $context);

        if (Feature::isActive('FEATURE_NEXT_10555')) {
            $customer['boundSalesChannelId'] = $this->getBoundSalesChannelId($customer['email'], $context);
        }

        $this->customerRepository->create([$customer], $context->getContext());

        $criteria = new Criteria([$customer['id']]);
        $criteria->addAssociation('addresses');
        $criteria->addAssociation('salutation');

        /** @var CustomerEntity $customerEntity */
        $customerEntity = $this->customerRepository->search($criteria, $context->getContext())->first();

        if ($customerEntity->getDoubleOptInRegistration()) {
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($this->getDoubleOptInEvent($customerEntity, $context, $data->get('storefrontUrl')));
        } elseif (!$customerEntity->getGuest()) {
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new CustomerRegisterEvent($context, $customerEntity));
        } else {
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new GuestCustomerRegisterEvent($context, $customerEntity));
        }

        $response = new CustomerResponse($customerEntity);

        if (!$customerEntity->getDoubleOptInRegistration()) {
            $newToken = $this->contextPersister->replace($context->getToken(), $context);
            $this->contextPersister->save(
                $newToken,
                [
                    'customerId' => $customerEntity->getId(),
                    'billingAddressId' => null,
                    'shippingAddressId' => null,
                ],
                Feature::isActive('FEATURE_NEXT_10058') ? $customerEntity->getId() : null
            );

            $event = new CustomerLoginEvent($context, $customerEntity, $newToken);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);

            $response->headers->set(PlatformRequest::HEADER_CONTEXT_TOKEN, $newToken);
        }

        // We don't want to leak the hash in store-api
        $customerEntity->setHash('');
        dump("act on register submit");
        return $response;
    }
}
```

My base class called **RegisterFormExtension.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace RegisterFormExtension;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;

class RegisterFormExtension extends Plugin{}
```

Here my **routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import resource="../../Storefront/Controller" type="annotation" />
</routes>
```

And here my **services.xml**

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="RegisterFormExtension\Storefront\Controller\CustomRegisterController" public="true">
            <!--<tag name="controller.service_arguments"></tag>-->
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Any help is highly apreciated :)

*EDIT A list of all routes currently...:

```
  [0 ] store-api.customer-group-registration.config
  [1 ] store-api.account.register.confirm
  [2 ] frontend.form.newsletter.register.handle
  [3 ] frontend.account.register.page
  [4 ] frontend.account.customer-group-registration.page
  [5 ] frontend.checkout.register.page
  [6 ] frontend.account.register.save
  [7 ] frontend.account.register.mail
  [8 ] store-api.account.register
  [9 ] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.detail
  [10] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.update
  [11] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.delete
  [12] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.list
  [13] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.search
  [14] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.search-ids
  [15] api.customer_group_registration_sales_channels.create


| Property     | Value                                                                                       |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | store-api.account.register                                                                  |
| Path         | /store-api/v{version}/account/register                                                      |
| Path Regex   | #^/store\-api/v(?P<version>[^/]++)/account/register$#sD                                     |
| Host         | ANY                                                                                         |
| Host Regex   |                                                                                             |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                                                         |
| Method       | POST                                                                                        |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                                                   |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                             |
| Defaults     | _controller: RegisterFormExtension\Storefront\Controller\CustomRegisterController::register |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Shopware but does "bin/console debug:router" show your route?

Comment: No! And that is driving me nut even more... wait i will show you the list.
I edit my question :)

Comment: When you want to add additional information then you should consider updating the question itself.  There is an edit button in the lower left corner.  Comments don't format well.  Even though Shopware runs on the Symfony framework it does some things a bit differently.  Extending a controller always takes a bit of care.  Hopefully, someone more familiar with Shopware will come along.

Comment: If you expand: [8 ] store-api.account.register what do you get?

Comment: Hey i edit my question :) Btw the profiler says : 
302 Redirect from  POST @frontend.account.register.save 
, so i tryied with @Route("/account/register", name="frontend.account.register.save", methods={"POST"}) but no luck.

Comment: @Cerad not sure if you got a notification of my comment :)

Comment: Ah and on 8 it seems to be my route. But why the method does not call ?